# How do I assign outputs of a function with multiple outputs to different varables in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, function

For example:

```
func createArray(_ oneArray: [Int],_ twoArray: [Int],_ threeArray: [Int],_ one: Int,_ two: Int,_ three: Int) -> (oneArrayNew: [Int], twoArrayNew: [Int], threeArrayNew: [Int]){

    // ...
    // ... *random code*
    // ...
    // ...

    return (oneArrayNew, twoArrayNew, threeArrayNew)

}
```

If I wanted to call this function again using my outputs of the first call `(oneArrayNew, twoArrayNew, threeArrayNew)` as the inputs now using the same function, how would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are talking about **tuples** here. Here is an example.

```
func blah(x: Int, y: Int) -> (a: Int, b: Int) {
    return (x,y)
}

let output = blah(1,1)

print(output.0, output.b) // You can access them using indices or the variable names. If they don't have names, you'll have to use indices.
```

And about passing the tuple as input, it was *deprecated* in Swift 2 something and later *removed* in Swift 3. So you have no other way than to pass the parameters individually.

```
blah(output.a, output.b)
```

Or you can even use multiple variables as shown in [@vacawama answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52214278/7734643).

Answer (score 1):

You can either assign the tuple to a variable such as `result` and then access each member:

```
let result = createArray(...
let result2 = createArray(result.oneArrayNew, result.twoArrayNew, ...
```

or you can assign the result of the call to a tuple to create three new variables:

```
let (a1, a2, a3) = createArray(...
let result2 = createArray(a1, a2, a3, ...
```

or even reuse the existing variables:

```
var (a1, a2, a3) = createArray(...
(a1, a2, a3) = createArray(a1, a2, a3, ...
```

---

**Complete Example:**

I implemented your function to create new arrays by dropping the first `N` items from each array.

Try this in a Playground:

```
func createArray(_ oneArray: [Int],_ twoArray: [Int],_ threeArray: [Int],_ one: Int,_ two: Int,_ three: Int) -> (oneArrayNew: [Int], twoArrayNew: [Int], threeArrayNew: [Int]){

    let oneArrayNew = Array(oneArray.dropFirst(one))
    let twoArrayNew = Array(twoArray.dropFirst(two))
    let threeArrayNew = Array(threeArray.dropFirst(three))

    return (oneArrayNew, twoArrayNew, threeArrayNew)
}

let result = createArray([1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12], 1, 2, 3)
print(result.oneArrayNew)    // [2, 3, 4]
print(result.twoArrayNew)    // [7, 8]
print(result.threeArrayNew)  // [12]

var (a1, a2, a3) = createArray([1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12], 2, 2, 2)
print(a1)  // [3, 4]
print(a2)  // [7, 8]
print(a3)  // [11, 12]

(a1, a2, a3) = createArray(a1, a2, a3, 1, 1, 1)
print(a1)  // [4]
print(a2)  // [8]
print(a3)  // [12]
```